# change color as one route o directions in google maps api v3 using?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know how to change the color of one or several sections of route service by changing the color of the section you select.

for example I have 3 cities and want the path 1-2 is blue and Route 2 to 3 is red

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the returned result, create separate polylines for the different color segments.

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 [DirectionsRendererOptions object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) only supports single color (and a native [google.maps.Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) can only have a single color).

Answer (score -1):

You would want to change the strokeColor of polyline using [google.maps.PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#PolylineOptions)

Comment: This is VLQ and doesn't answer OP's question.